# Locust example doesn't work in Helm Chart Delevery Hero but works on my mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, locust

I just copy the example from from the locust site.

```
from locust import HttpUser, task, User

class HelloWorld(User):
    @task
    def hello_world(self):
        self.client.get("/hello")
        self.client.get("/world")
```

I get the following error

```
No tasks defined on HelloWorld. Use the @task decorator or set the 'tasks' attribute of the User (or mark it as abstract = True if you only intend to subclass it)
```

I was expecting the example to work getting same error for simple test but it works on my mac aswell. Did I miss something.

Comment: Maybe try filing a ticket in the deliveryhero repo? I have no idea why you’d get that error..

Comment: Hey, wait a minute! You’re subclassing User, you should be subclassing HttpUser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So hopefully this helps someone in my helm chart I declared a tag and forgot about it. So it was filtering according to that tag... thus not running any tasks! Resolved!